# CSS Image button with additional small image

Tags: html, css

I need to create an image button. Based on some state I may need to add tiny superscript image to the right of initial image (like exclamation mark, asterisk etc).

Button can be any html element, probably it'll be something like this (but it's not mandatory; really need a button with a navigatable action preferably without javascript)

```
<a href="somewhere.html"><span class="image-file" /></a>

.image-button {
  background-image: url(file.png);
  width: 40px;
  height: 60px;
}
```

Suppose there are images "asterisk.png", "exlamation-mark.png".

Of course I could define another class

```
.image-file-error {
  background-image: url(fileWithExlamationMark.png);
  width: 40px;
  height: 60px;
}
```

and apply it, when applicable.
But then I would have to merge file.png and exlamation-mark.png into 1 additional fileWithExlamationMark.png image.

In addition there are other main images to which these connotation images can apply meaning more merging images will be needed.

I'm sure there is css for it, but I can't remember the trick.
Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think you need to merge images. If it's one image and you are trying to show another image why not nest these in an element then hide your connotation and show when needed with a sub class?

Comment: How can I do it? I'm not very well versed in CSS. You suggest to have .asterisk { background-image... } and then do <span class="image-file asterisk" />?

Comment: `background-image` can have multiple images, each positioned differently. You could assign a different class to the element based on what additional image you need to show. And that class can contain the rules for `background image`

Comment: I wouldn't suggest multi background images with position. Sure the load time probably isn't going to be noticed in these days, though there's plenty more reasons for it. To have a hidden div holding the image in question and load that after page load you would be better off. My question is are you trying to show an image over another image? Please show an example with simple screen shot or drawings